# Django reverse lookup foreign keys with multiple conditions

Tags: django

I am trying to do a reverse lookup in Django with multiple conditions, hopefully, my question does not duplicate with other questions. Let me explain:

I have two models:
Model A:

```
class A(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ... other fields
```

Model B:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ... other fields
```

How can I get A that:
1) has a B with label = name, value=John
2) and, has a B with label =age, value =20

I tried the following, it does not work:

```
A.objects.filter(b__label="name", b__value="John", b__label="age", b__value=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Q object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

A.objects.filter(
    (Q(b__label="name") & Q(b__value="John")) | (Q(b__label="age") & Q(b__value=20))
)
```

Comment: Thanks but that will not work. Because I want the relationshiop to be `AND` not `OR`. If I change it to ```A.objects.filter(
    (Q(b__label="name") & Q(b__value="John")) & (Q(b__label="age") & Q(b__value=20))
)```. I got **0**, which is not correct.